# How to correctly store/pass a variable of interface type (modern c++)?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, c++14

I have two interfaces: `INetwork` and `IController`. Class `App` would store implementations of both interfaces as it's fields. Both interfaces should be able to access public methods of each other. It would look something like:

```
class INetwork
{
public:
    virtual ~INetwork() {}
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
    virtual void setController(IController*);
}

class IController
{
public:
    virtual ~IController() {}
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
    virtual void setNetwork(INetwork*);
}

class Controller : public IController
{
    void do_something() override;
}

class Network : public INetwork
{
    void do_something() override;
}

class App
{
private:
    IController *controller;
    INetwork *network;

    void initialize()
    {
        controller = new Controller(); //todo: factory
        network = new Network(); //todo: factory
        controller.setNetwork(network);
        network.setController(controller);
    }
}
```

The idea:

- `Network` and `Controller` are two separate entities that would evolve over time (`ControllerV1`, `ControllerV2`, `ControllerMultithreaded`, `NetworkHttp`, `NetworkModbus`, etc.), but I still need to maintain backward compatibility and concrete implementations would depend on the configuration. This is why I use interfaces.
- `Network` and `Controller` would be able to control each other depending on the various events, state changes and so on. This is why I pass them to each other via `setController(IController*)` and `setNetwork(INetwork*)`. I would also like to implement Observer patter for both `Network` and `Controller`.

Now by main problem is that I am not sure how to correctly implement all my ideas using the modern C++11/14 approaches. 
Should I store `INetwork` and `IController` an simple pointer within the `App` or should I use `std::shared_ptr` here? How to store and pass references to `INetwork` within `IController` and vice-versa?
Are there any issues in inheritance?

C++ provides several instruments and I am a bit lost here.

### TL&DR

1. Should I use raw pointer or is it better to switch to std::shared_ptr?
2. What do you think about inheritance scheme?

Comment: The best way for you to figure out the best solution is to study how all the modern C++ language feature, than you mention, work, and how to use them. Once you have learned how they work, you will be in an informed position to make the best design decision for your specific requirements and applications.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You are right, but unfortunately the amount of time it takes to have a deep understanding of all the features is "considerable"  at best, but the actual work and projects usually have strict timeframes and limits. I am not lazy and I do read and experiment on my own , but right now an advice from C++ guru would be very appreciated.

Comment: You don't have interfaces, but abstract classes (and this is very different). C++ don't have interfaces but classes, templates and soon [concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: Nobody has ever accused C++ of being easy. It is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Any kind of "advice" given here has just as much chance of being right, as being wrong. There are no "easy" buttons, or magic shortcuts, when it comes to C++. You have to know what you're doing, and how to do it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes. But thats the basic process of learning things: you learn/research and than you ask questions about the things you were unable to understand. Regarding my question: Qt, for example, uses raw pointers for inheritance, but the way I see it, it increases the change of messing thing up.

Comment: I would use `std::unique_ptr` in the `App` class, and pass raw pointers to each other. In that way you avoid the overhead of `std::shared_ptr`, but also make your code simpler (no destructor needed in the `App` class).

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-and-only correct answer to the questions you're asking.

There are different ways of storing/passing variables that are interfaces and you've mentioned some of those ways. Some other ways of dealing with this depend on what you're ultimately trying to achieve.

For instance, if you're ultimately concerned about having polymorphic behavior **and** you're not tied to that being a design/type detail, you can also consider using type erasure and storing/passing these entities by value (semantically speaking). As to the how and why you might want to do it this way — which also addresses your question regarding issues with using inheritance — I'd suggest watching Sean Parent's talk: [Inheritance Is The Base Class of Evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIhUE5uUFOA).

As to which way you should go, that's a matter of opinion which is better suited for a site like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I guess I see my issue with this questions: I should narrow it down to more concrete problems.